# AngularJS request interceptor and http-auth-interceptor

Tags: angularjs, angular-http-interceptors

I'm using https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth with much success to popup a modal if a user is not logged in.   I am trying to preempt all requests from even going out if the user isn't authenticated.  Currently, when the user hits the app, it'll pop up the modal, as expected, but on successful login, resending the buffered requests returns the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined
at urlIsSameOrigin (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14340:17)
at sendReq (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8256:25)
at $http.serverRequest (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7995:16)
at wrappedCallback (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11485:81)
at wrappedCallback (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11485:81)
at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11571:26
at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12595:28)
at Scope.$digest (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12407:31)
at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12699:24)
at done (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8287:45)
```

It appears that the code buffers two requests for templates, then pops up the modal.  Upon successfully getting past the modal, sendReq is run on the two buffered requests, as well as on the return of those requests, and those requests error in urlIsSameOrigin.  Does anybody have any suggestions?  Here is my module:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app')
  .factory('myAuth', ['$http','mySessionService','authService','$rootScope', function ($http, mySessionService, authService, $rootScope) {
    return {

      /* snip */

    };
  }])
  .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {

    function isAuthenticated(mySessionService) {
      var session = mySessionService.getUserProfile();
      if(typeof session !== 'undefined' && !!session.username){
        return true;
      }
      return false
    }

    function isWhiteListed(url){
      switch (url){
        case "views/login.html":
        case "api/auth/":
          return true;
        default:
          return false;
      }
    }

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$rootScope', '$q', 'httpBuffer', 'mySessionService',function($rootScope, $q, httpBuffer,mySessionService) {
      return {
        request: function(config) {
          //if not logged in    and not login form or auth endpoint:
          if(!isAuthenticated(mySessionService) && !isWhiteListed(config.url)){

            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $rootScope.$broadcast('event:auth-loginRequired', config);
            httpBuffer.append(config, deferred);
            return deferred.promise;
          }

          return config || $q.when(config);
        }
      }
    }]);
  }])
```

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I'm wrestling with it right now